# PHP CURL запрос нестандартного заголовка

Tags: php, curl

Есть ответ от сервера, содержащий кастомный заголовок errcode:

```
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 09:06:04 GMT
errcode: 1
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

401 Unauthorized
```

Как получить при помощи CURL значение errcode?

Comment: как все остальные заголовки

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот тут есть хороший пример как получить заголовки ответа с помощью PHP cURL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/php-curl-retrieving-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request

Функция `curl_exec` по-умолчанию не возвращает заголовки. Чтобы заголовки появились, нужно предварительно установить опцию `CURLOPT_HEADER`, тогда `curl_exec` вернет строку, в которой сначала будут идти заголовки, а потом тело ответа. После выполнения запроса можно будет получить длинну подстроки заголовка с помощью `curl_getinfo` с опцией `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE`, и тогда тело ответа будет легко отделить от заголовков вручную.

Пример кода:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
// ...

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// Then, after your curl_exec call:
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);
```

Чтобы получить из переменной `$header` заголовки в формате ключ-значение, можно сделать что-то подобное:

```
$headerRows = array_slice(preg_split('/(\\r?\\n)/', $header), 1);
$headers = [];
foreach ($headerRows as $headerRow) {
    list($headerName, $headerValue) = explode(':', $headerRow);
    $headers[$headerName] = $headerValue;                
}
```